# combne react-dates with a timepicker component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-dates

**I added 2 animated GIF for more specificity to the problem.**

Hello I work a react project to combine `airbnb/react-dates` with a `timepicker` custom component.

The workflow is:
1. User choses a day on the 1st opened calendar `<SingleDatePicker />`
2. `<SingleDatePicker>` is hidden and a `timepicker component` is shown.
3. User choses a time and `timepicker`, calendar date/time updated, and then its hidden.
4. 2nd `<SingleDatePicker>` is enabled, focused & opened.
5. Same procedure as the 1st `<SingleDatePicker>`

### Problem

I cant destinquish when to show the timepicker and when not.
This is because of the `focusChange` function :

 `focusChange({ focused }, calendar, timePicker) {
    // handle the visiblility of calendars & timepickers
    this.setState({
      [calendar]: focused,
      [`show${timePicker}`]: !focused
    });
  }`

**cases:**
1. Calendar is open, user clicks outside => calendar closes but timepicker opens. (Should hide timepicker as well)
**See GIF:**
[image]
2. User choses day & choses time (1st calendar) => 2nd calendar opens.
When we click interchangable between the calendars (Inputs), 1st & 2nd, there is always the opposite timepicker opened.
**See GIF:**

[image]

### You can play on Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/5v459yrwk4?fontsize=14

What i need, is to know when the calendar closes bacause of a day selection, so to open the timepicker, and when it closes because of a `clickoutside` so not to display a `timepicker`.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You are already showing timepicker with handleDatesChange. If I remove it from focusChange I see only one problem and that is closing timepicker on outside click. Or did I misunderstand your post?

Comment: If you remove timepicker from `focusChange` it will displays when you click detween calendars (actually when you click on the <input> texts of each calendar)